# Load videos in listView just once by using an url on android

Tags: android, listview, caching

I have a listView of videos that are loaded by using an URL, but every time I run my app, videoView loads video coming from a host server and this make my app so slow. Can I cache videos? Or Is there a another solution?

Comment: you just store all data in database

Comment: Ofc you can cache them. Just be precise about what http lib you're using and we'll lead through the process of caching.